# Limits problem: Factoring a cube root of x?

Tags: limits

Disclaimer: I am an adult learning Calculus.  This is not a student posting his homework assignment.  I think this is a great forum!

$$\lim_{x\to8}{\frac{\sqrt[3] x-2}{x-8}}$$

How do I factor the top to cancel the $x-8$ denominator?

Comment: See also: [How do I find $\lim_{x \to 8} \frac{(\sqrt[3]{x} -2)}{x-8}$ by using the conjugate rule?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3516838)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you need to factor the denominator: $x-8 = (\sqrt[3]{x})^3-2^3 = (\sqrt[3]{x}-2)\left((\sqrt[3]{x})^2+2\sqrt[3]{x}+2^2\right)$.

Comment: Selected for most brevity.

Answer (score 10):

The objective here is to factor the *denominator*, viewing it as the difference of cubes.

This might be easier to see if you put $t=\sqrt[\large 3]x.\; $ Then $\;x = t^3,\;$ and the corresponding (equivalent) limit becomes  $$\lim_{t\to 2}\; \dfrac {t - 2}{t^3 - 8} = \lim_{t\to 2}\;\frac{t-2}{(t-2)(t^2 + 2t + 4)}$$

Comment: Exactly what I thought to post. +1

Comment: @amWhy: I agree with Don! +1

Comment: This is a brilliant way to look at this problem! Thanks for sharing :)